# *ngIf com boolean

Tags: ionic, angular

Tenho um argumento booleano em um *ngIf, contudo ele parece não funcionar. Caso o argumento seja verdadeiro:

```
<ion-input type="text" *ngIf="produto.fracionado"  value="Sim" readonly></ion-input>
```

Caso o argumento seja falso:

```
<ion-input type="text" *ngIf="!produto.fracionado" value="Não" readonly></ion-input>
```

Contudo sempre é me retornado "Sim", mesmo para os casos do argumento false.

Comment: Parece funcionar (https://jsbin.com/yoqufoceva/edit?html,js,output). Tem certeza se o Angular está carregado corretamente na página?

Comment: Tenho certeza porque o resto da página funciona corretamente. Ficou faltando falar que estou usando o Ionic e o Angular 3.1.1.

Comment: Desculpa pelo erro, o core do Angular é 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

se o resultado que você está recebendo for `"Não"` então ele vai sempre retornar `true` pois `"Não"` é uma `string` válida você precisa trabalhar as variáveis booleanas sempre com `false` e `true`, ou `0` e `1`

Answer (score 0):

O seu html esta correto.
Você pode me mostrar o resultado do seu objeto.
Eu fiz uma simulação no meu projeto com Ionic 3 desta forma:

```
public produto: object = {
    fracionado: false
}
```